# Cloud watch eks auto scale solution with java/node JDK and terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am deploying my environment through terraform, I have a sqs against which I have set cloud watch alarms. My question is based on cloudwatch alarm can I set my eks to autoscale.

My next question is that if there is a way to do it through nodes/java

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? Just use the cluster-autoscaler https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie here. How will you integrate cloudwatch alarms to cluster-autoscaler, through external metrics. If yes, is there an example which can be referred.